# Ng-if on select element

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to show content depending on the option selected from the user. I tried this way

```
              <select class="form-control" id="Intervencion" >
                <option selected disabled></option>
                <option (click)="show">Yes</option>
                <option>No</option></select>

<div *ngIf="show"><p>Text to show</p></div>
```

I do not understand the problem. There is a special directive for this?

Comment: What is `show`?

Comment: What do you really expect `(click)="show"` to do? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... You don't seem to know how basic HTML works. Sorry to say that, but you have to be aware of what you're doing is completely barbaric.

Here is the solution for you :

```
<select [(ngModel)]="intervencion">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="intervencion === 'yes'">Text to show</div>
```

That being given, you should really follow Angular's tutorials, because that's one of the first examples they give to explain how `ngModel` works.

Comment: Thanks! It works. But the first option that i use as placeholder disappears.

Comment: You can use a placeholder on the select to show a placeholder

Comment: "what you're doing is completely barbaric" You could have helped him without roasting him. At some point, we were all beginners to some technology and did some rookie mistakes.

Comment: And like my father did to me, sometimes you need to tell the truth to someone in order to make them aware of their lack of knowledge. I'm not buying that "be kind" stuff, and I don't need you to comment on my behavior without helping the OP.

Comment: (and by the way, I apologized for that, right on the spot, I don't call it a roast, but whatever floats your boat)